# jQuery masonry plugin not working in IE7

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, internet-explorer-7, jquery-masonry

i am working on a page that uses the [masonry jQuery plugin](http://masonry.desandro.com/) to layout blocks on a page. It works fine in all browsers except IE7 (yes, it even works in IE6), but i cannot figure out why it is happening as there are no js errors. The worst part is that it seems to work on initial page load, then it freaks out after a second and sets the left and top values of the blocks to 0.

[Here is a link](http://www.topshop.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/CatalogNavigationSearchResultCmd?catalogId=33057&storeId=12556&langId=-1&viewAllFlag=false&categoryId=312992&interstitial=true) to a test version of the page. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you find a solution?I am also having problems in IE7 to IE9 but a bit different. The images does not stack up in towards the top. Even the official demo does not look the same as in other browsers:
http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/images.html

Comment: "height: auto" on the items seems to do the trick for me. Found that from your site's css.

Answer (score 3):

May be, I found how to solve the problem. Just like

```
$GPContainer.masonry(
{
    singleMode: true,
    itemSelector    : '.pin',
    //define in css
    columnWidth     : 0,
    isAnimated      : true,
    isFitWidth      : true,
    isRTL           : false
});
```

After

```
"isRTL : false"
```

can't have `,` or it will be wrong in IE7.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I want to apply the masonry plugin on the nono-visible divs. In Firefox and other normal browser was ok but not in IE. I've modified and applied the masonry plugin after the divs was visible and now it seems to be ok. (Sorry for my english :) )